# PHP can't file contact.html, but it shouldn't exist? (Smarty Engine)

Tags: php, html, apache, smarty

I've got a legacy PHP project to fix a thing or two. I've downloaded it via FileZilla and served it on my local machine with a local copy of the database. The project is exactly the same with the live one, yet the live one can open the **url/contact.html** but on my machine it says **no such file is found**. All other pages go for url/categories/ or url/products/ so I've tried altering the url but no use.

All the other pages within the site are simple: one .php controller one .php model and one .tpl smarty template view. Requiring no .html at all. But this one is somehow different. The .htaccess file is exactly the same as the live version. I've tried adding a rewrite rule to direct every .html to .php but didn't work. I'm lost and out of options, please help? It doesn't even have to be an answer,"Try looking into that" would work too.

I'm working via XAMPP on windows, and I've configured the https:// to http:// on my project but that's all. Even hidden files are checked and confirmed.

Comment: have you checked your .htaccess? Why a rewrite rule from html to php?

Comment: 1) have checked that contact.html is a static file (like a real existing html file?)
2) is there some kind of "routing" within the PHP of the project?

Answer (score 0):

1. have checked that contact.html is a static file (like a real existing html file?)
2. is there some kind of "routing" within the PHP of the project? If there is route urls might be really anyware.. in the mysql database, redis, a json file and whatnot.. have seen them all.
3. try to debug where and how it works on the "production" server by using some logging to a file edit the file through filezilla and log to a 'mylog.log' file until you find out what is going on.. or if the site is not used all the time by clients - you can just try to echo stuff to figure out how this exact /contact.html works